# Find the eigenvectors and eigenvalues of a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

Given the linear transformation $T(at^2+bt+c)=(2a − c)t^2 + (2a + b − 2c)t + (−a + 2c)$, how can I find the eigenvectors and eigenvalues? I know that general idea is to solve $T(v)=\lambda v$. From there, I get:
$$\lambda at^2+ \lambda bt+ \lambda c = (2a − c)t^2 + (2a + b − 2c)t + (−a + 2c)$$

This implies,

$$2a - c = \lambda a$$
$$2a + b - 2c = \lambda b$$
$$-a + 2c = \lambda c$$

This is where I get stuck. How can I solved this system? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: How is $t$ related to $x$?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. Thanks for pointing it out! Fixed.

Comment: It took me a second to see that $T$ is defined on the set of all quadratic polynomials with values in the same set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that you are looking for *non-zero* solutions to $T(v) = \lambda v$. Rewrite your system as
$$
(2 - \lambda )a + 0 b - c = 0\\
2a + (1 - \lambda) b - 2c = 0\\
-a + 0b + (2 - \lambda c) = 0
$$
That is, we are looking for non-zero solutions to the equation
$$
\pmatrix{2 - \lambda & 0 & -1\\ 2 & 1-\lambda & -2\\-1 & 0 & 2 - \lambda} \pmatrix{a\\b\\c} = \pmatrix{0\\0\\0}.
$$
However, note that for a square matrix $M$, the equation $Mx = 0$ will have a non-zero solution if and only if $\det(M) = 0$. The determinant of $M$ is a polynomial on the variable $\lambda$. If you compute and expand correctly, you should get
$$
\det(M) = 0 \implies \\
-λ^3 + 5 λ^2 - 7 λ + 3 = 0 \implies\\
(\lambda - 3)(\lambda - 1)^2 = 0.
$$
The zeros of the polynomial are $1$ and $3$, which means that those are the eigenvalues of the transformation.

Now that you have the eigenvalues, you can plug these values of $\lambda$ back in and solve for the eigenvectors.

Answer (score 0):

That system is equivalent to the system$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}(2-\lambda)a-c=0\\2a+(1-\lambda)b-2c=0\\-a+(2-\lambda)c=0,\end{array}\right.$$which has non-trivial solutions if abd only if$$\begin{vmatrix}2-\lambda&0&-1\\2&1-\lambda&-2\\-1&0&2-\lambda\end{vmatrix}=0.\tag1$$But the LHS of $(1)$ is$$(1-\lambda)\begin{vmatrix}2-\lambda&-1\\-1&2-\lambda\end{vmatrix}=(1-\lambda)\bigl((2-\lambda)^2-1\bigr)=-(\lambda-1)^2(\lambda-3).$$Can you take it from here?